# Using IdentityServer with ASP.NET + embedded SPA JS framework

Tags: javascript, asp.net, identityserver4

I'm sorry if the title is not very clear.

What I have: ASP.NET application with "embedded" Vue.js 2 from this repo: https://github.com/MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-Vue-starter

I already studied Identity Server 4 manuals so I tried hybrid flow with pure ASP.NET and implicit flow using oidc-client with pure JS. Both flows work for me.

But what I want is using JS page that hosted in ASP.NET to get access token and refresh token and store them in ASP.NET. ASP.NET in this case acts as a backend (but not the Resource API!).

Maybe (optional) there is a way to create custom login form. User fill this form, JS sends login and password to ASP.NET backend and than in turn transmits them to Identity Server and retrieves tokens.

I wonder if it is possible to use such a scenario at all and whether it is viable and sufficiently safe.

Any assumptions are welcome!

EDIT:
What I really want is to use Vue just for display my data while using ASP.NET as a backend-client which gathers information from resource API.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the Login page - no, you can't. Reason - when using OIDC authentication, you are delegating the login functionality to the provider (in your case Identity Server), and it takes care for the login page and etc.

Now regarding your Vue app. Vue is a SPA. SPA's can only use [Implicit](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/grant_types.html#implicit) grant type and by this - they are not being issued a refresh token.

Your solution here is to use the oidc-client-js library with your Vue app. We have this scenario implemented (Vue on top of aspnet core) and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: I used oidc-client and only access token in JS SPA. But what are then benefits of using ASP.NET as a host? It will act in this scenario as resource API and that is not what I want. I want ASP.NET to be also a client. Furthemore the best solution for me would be all authentication performed at ASP.NET level and use JS only to display results.

Comment: Well then your client will be the ASP.NET, and you can perform Hybrid grant type. You have to select - either the SPA or the ASP.NET that is hosting it should be the client. You can't go with both. If you want ASP.NET to be your client, and use JS only for displaying results, then why do you need Vue?

Comment: @ m3n7alsnak3 I'm using Vue just because I don't know frontend and this is first framework I learned :) And I don't want to use Razor pages cause they are not so convenient as Vue components for my purposes. Could you suggest me the way to use js only for visualization? As I can see I can create of corse page on Razor to login and then use Vue.js for displaying results but it looks a bit ugly for me.

Comment: @xneg - and also sounds wrong. You should not mix them. First of all - how are you going to display the data in Vue, if you don't want to make API calls to retrieve it? You also don't want to use Razor pages. How are you going to provide the data to Vue? You are mixing concepts here.

Comment: that's why I'm asking. Of course I will call controller methods from Vue but I don't want it to keep any tokens. I want the tokens to be stored on the ASP.NET side. Again if it's not possible - ok. But I try to understand what concept breaks making it impossible.

Comment: If you store the tokens on the ASP.NET side, you are loosing the SPA functionality of vue, because you simply can't make the calls, without the tokens. And may I ask - what are your considerations from not keeping the tokens on the browser side? (Actually the token is only one - the access_token)

Comment: There are two reasons: first - my ASP.NET should be client too. I dont want the scenario from examples where SPA is client and ASP.NET is resource API. Second - I try to understand what are benefits of hosting SPA with ASP.NET. And the more I dive into situation (taking into account your suggestions too) the more I think that dividing them into separate projects would be better.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177677/discussion-between-xneg-and-m3n7alsnak3).